# Why does the last cell show up in the third to last position in a UITableView?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've got a `UITableView` filled with `UITableViewCells`.

Now when I scroll down, there's a problem with the two bottom cells. The last cell shows up as the third from the bottom and there are two additional cells below which shouldn't be there.

What are possible causes of such a behavior?

<sub>Editor's note: I hope I correctly interpreted the question. The problem could also be that the last two cells don't show up at all.</sub>

Comment: I think you can get better help if you post the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

The number of cells in the table view stems from the delegate method numberOfRowsInSection:. Check what number is being set here, if you're counting an array then NSLog the count ([MyArray count]) and check to see if its as you expect. Its the only thing I can think of that would lead to additional or missing cells in your tableview without source code